# What is considered a Schema Change using Java Spring?

Tags: database, spring, schema

What is considered a schema change using Java Spring ?

More specific, I need to know if adding a value to an enum is considered a schema change.

I remember once reading that only adding/removing members from objects having `@Entity` or `@Bean` is considered a schema change but I cannot find the source now.

Comment: That depends how your enum is stored. If your column also is enum typed then yes it is a schema change. Else it might be a data change depending on what you use as value the `ordinal` (position in the enum) or not.

Answer (score 0):

That question isn't related to Spring (or not even Java I guess).

It depends if it is a schema change or not.

1. Is your column a `(var)char` and too short to hold the new value, then it is a schema change. Same applies if you use numeric values and use a `bit` or `short` and have more values.
2. If you column itself is an [enum type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/enum.html). Then it is a schema change as you would need to change the supported values.

If non of this applies it could be a data change. Depending on how you store the value of the enum. If you store a textual representation of the enum you are ok. If you are using ordinal then you might need to migrate data. This depends on if you are adding the value at the end, or between other element.